# How to access a particular chunk of div with javascript

Tags: javascript, this

from

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, function(event) {
  if (parseInt(event.jPlayer.status.currentPercentAbsolute) >= 2 ) {
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").unbind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate) 
    debugger
  }
});
```

"this" =

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
    <img id="jp_poster_0" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: none;">
    <audio id="jp_audio_0" preload="metadata" src="http://localhost:3000/system/songs/song_files/000/000/054/original/9_horwood_-_gotta_get_out_of_the_city.wav?1492962591" title="Gotta Get Out Of The City"></audio>
</div>
```

I need to grab the audio src, but I can't get it.   any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: You can do it with - `$('#jquery_jplayer_1').find('audio').attr('src');`

Comment: var audiosrc = $(this).find("audio").attr("src")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var thisIsAudioSrc = $('#jp_audio_0').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .attr() function (https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the value of the src attribute.

like so

```
var audioSrc = $('#jp_audio_0').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the `src` attribute of your `audio` element by using something like below -

```
$('#jquery_jplayer_1').find('audio').attr('src');
```

Here is a working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/2whaz67p/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
var src = $('#jp_audio_0').attr('src');
console.log(src);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"><img id="jp_poster_0" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: none;"><audio id="jp_audio_0" preload="metadata" src="/system/songs/song_files/000/000/054/original/9_horwood_-_gotta_get_out_of_the_city.wav?1492962591" title="Gotta Get Out Of The City"></audio></div>
```